# Can you pass the name of a property to a function in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a struct containing a bunch of properties referencing different types of statistics.  A sample object is:

```
class Stats {
    var stats: [Stat]
}
struct Stat {
    var id: UUID
    var countA: Int
    var countB: Int
    var countC: Int
    var totalAAttempts: Int
    var totalBAttempts: Int
    var totalCAttempts: Int
    ...
}
```

I am displaying the percentages with a bunch of functions in the class...

```
class Stats {
    var stats: [Stat]
    var countAPerc: Double {
        let totalA = stats.reduce(0) { total, stat in
            total + stat.countA
        }
        let totalAttemps = stats.reduce(0) { total, stat in
            total + stat.totalAAttempts
        }
        return Double(totalA) / Double(totalAttempts)
    }
    var countAPercDisplay: String {
        String(format: "%.1f", countAPerc * 100) + "%"
    }
    var countBPerc: Double {
        let totalB = stats.reduce(0) { total, stat in
            total + stat.countB
        }
        let totalAttemps = stats.reduce(0) { total, stat in
            total + stat.totalBAttempts
        }
        return Double(totalB) / Double(totalAttempts)
    }
    var countBPercDisplay: String {
        String(format: "%.1f", countBPerc * 100) + "%"
    }
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to specify the name of the property as a parameter in a function to prevent the same code from being written over and over?  Something like:

```
func summarizeProperty(_ countProperty: PROPERTYNAME1, _ totalProperty: PROPERTYNAME2) -> Double {
    let totalCount = stats.reduce(0) { total, stat in
        total + stat.PROPERTYNAME1
    }
    let totalAttemps = stats.reduce(0) { total, stat in
        total + stat.PROPERTYNAME2
    }
    return Double(totalCount) / Double(totalAttempts)
}

func summarizedProperty(_ countProperty: PROPERTYNAME1, _ totalProperty: PROPERTYNAME2) -> String {
    let summarized = summarizeProperty(PROPERTYNAME1, PROPERTYNAME2)
    return String(format: "%.1f", summarized * 100) + "%"
}
```

And then call it...

```
Text(summarizedProperty(countA, totalAAttempts))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look up `KeyPath`: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-power-of-key-paths-in-swift/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool you want here is a [KeyPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keypath):

```
func summarizeProperty(_ countProperty: KeyPath<Stat, Int>, _ totalProperty: KeyPath<Stat, Int>) -> Double {
    let totalCount = stats.reduce(0) { total, stat in
        total + stat[keyPath: countProperty]
    }
    let totalAttempts = stats.reduce(0) { total, stat in
        total + stat[keyPath: totalProperty]
    }
    return Double(totalCount) / Double(totalAttempts)
}
```

A `KeyPath<Stat, Int>` is property on Stat that returns an Int. It is accessed using the `keyPath:` subscript and generally created using the `\` syntax :

```
Stats().summarizeProperty(\.countA, \.totalAAttempts)
```

KeyPaths are normal values and can be passed around like this:

```
func summarizedProperty(_ countProperty: KeyPath<Stat, Int>, _ totalProperty: KeyPath<Stat, Int>) -> String {
    let summarized = summarizeProperty(countProperty, totalProperty)
    return String(format: "%.1f", summarized * 100.0) + "%"
}
```